# Magneto2 NO customer order history on frontend under My Account, orders only visible from Admin?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

Testing our Magento 2.3.1 site after migration and new development completed. We are about to go live then I saw a problem with viewing the customer order history under My Account > My Orders. Shows the following message "You have placed no orders."

I can view this test customers orders in Admin, all old orders and new orders show up normally. This lack of order history happens with old and newly created customers.

I feel there is something weird going on with how the customer account relates/configured to the store. If so where in the DB should I be looking to validate this hunch?

Has anyone seen anything like this, Thanks for your help!

I have tested this using old imported customers from 1.9.4 and new customers. No change in order history shown.

I expect to see the full history of my customers orders. instead, I'm greeted with a "You have placed no orders." message.

Comment: I'd check the magento exception logs and see if anything looks amiss there

Comment: @zack6849 I took a look at the Magento exception logs and did not find anything out of the ordinary. Nothing logged when I was placing an order or looking up an order as a customer. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Check the community github page for issues matching yourdescription, or if you have to get down and dirty, set it up locally, attach a debugger, and trace it step by step till you figure out what the problem is, i'd make sure your page isn't caching that page for some reason for logged out vs logged in customers